# Why is my ApplicationDbContext getting disposed when I dispose of UserManager/RoleManager in my database initializer Seed()?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm playing with MVC 5, and I've created a website that uses ASP.NET Identity.  I followed the steps in [this blog post on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/20/building-a-simple-todo-application-with-asp-net-identity-and-associating-users-with-todoes.aspx) to create a user and a role in the `Seed` method for my database initializer.

However, I noticed that the `UserManager` and `RoleManager` used in that code both implement IDisposable, so I changed the code slightly, to look something like this (and thus dispose them once I've finished with them):

```
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        using (var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context)))
        using (var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context)))
        {
            EnsureRoleCreated(roleManager, Roles.Administrator);

            const string AdministratorUserName = "admin";
            const string DefaultAdminPassword = "password";

            var user = EnsureUserCreated(userManager, AdministratorUserName, DefaultAdminPassword);

            EnsureUserIsInRole(userManager, user, Roles.Administrator);
        }


        base.Seed(context);
    }
```

Now, when my controller actions attempt to access the DB, I get an exception saying that my `DbContext` has been disposed. (I new up a `DbContext` instance in the constructor for my controller).

[If I remove those `using()` statements and thus do not dispose the `UserManager` and `RoleManager`, then the problem goes away, so it's definitely those `using()` statements that are making the difference.]

This seems very odd to me. If the "correct" way to deal with this is to **not** explicitly dispose the `UserManager` and `RoleManager`, then surely they will still be disposed eventually when the garbage collector kicks in. Since this is unpredictable and could happen at any time, does this not mean that I have a ticking time-bomb in my application?

It seems to me that since I created the `DbContext`, I should be responsible for disposing of it. Why the heck are `UserManager` and/or `RoleManager` disposing of something they did not create?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the `RoleStore` that disposes the `DbContext` even if it did not create it.
The `UserStore` has a `DisposeContext` bool property that controls if the context should be disposed or not. The `DisposeContext` is false if you use the constructor that takes a `DbContext` as input.

This seems to have been fixed in the [nightly builds](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/09/asp-net-identity-nuget-packages-for-the-nightly-builds-are-available-on-myget.aspx). Here the RoleStore also have the `DisposeContext` property and seems to work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. Glad to hear it's not deliberate behaviour.